# Django Admin error Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:" "

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

I keep getting the following error when I attempt to create a `list_display` in my django `admin.py` file. `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Penguin Books'`

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = 'title', 'publisher'

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30L)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey('Publisher', db_column='publisher')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'book'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app/books/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'books')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
```

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,    **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
372.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
  1285.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  90.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in iterator
  301.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in results_iter
  775.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  41.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py" in execute
  120.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in execute
  176.         if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
File "C:\Python27E\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in _warning_check
   92.                     warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)

Exception Type: Warning at /admin/app/books/
Exception Value: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Penguin Books'
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop your table (or database) and then run `syncdb` again.  You should do this after you make changes in your models.

The error is because your database is storing the column `Publisher` as a `DOUBLE` and you are trying to insert a string `Penguin Books` in it.

Either you have made changes to your model and didn't drop and recreate the tables (by running `syncdb`), or you are doing something like this:

```
book = Book()
book.title = 'Some Title'
book.publisher = 'Penguin Books'
book.save()
```

The problem with the above is that `publisher` is a foreign key, so you need to add a reference to the `Publisher` model, so something like this:

```
 publisher = Publisher()
 publisher.name = 'Penguin Books'
 publisher.save()

 book = Book()
 book.title = 'Some Title'
 book.publisher = publisher # here you are assigning the "Publisher" object
 book.save()
```

Comment: I think you've got it right. I just saw your answer after I wrote mine. But I think you've got it right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple because you did not register those names in the `fields` parameter.

This is how it should look like:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'publisher')
    list_display = ('title', 'publisher')

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Comment: I added the `fields` parameter and the parentheses that you included in your example and was still unsuccessful. The same error occurred.

Comment: Then I believe that this is a problem with database storage. Clear everything in your DB, and then run `syncdb` again. That should do the trick. In the future use migration tools like `south`.